# Transaction test mode in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, unit-testing, transactions

I saw in the docs about CodeIgniter:

> "you can optionally put the transaction system into "test mode", which
>   will cause your queries to be rolled back -- even if the queries
>   produce a valid result. To use test mode simply set the first
>   parameter in the `$this->db->trans_start()` function to `TRUE`"

---

I understand that able to use transaction (test_mode) to support database fixture for testing insert, update, delete. But it still affects to Database. I set db_debug is TRUE.
Any idea about this problem? Thanks so much.

```
Example code in my controller:

public function __construct(){
  //load database library and model
   $this->load->library('database');
   $this->load->model('message_mdl');
}

public function do()
{
    $data_insert = array('message' => 'hello');
    $this->db->trans_start(true);
    $this->message_mdl->insert($data_insert);
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this its not working for me too. I don't know why! I'll trying to find the reason. 'll get back here with proper method. If you find it out pls let me know too.

But I tried the alternate method, its working fine.

```
public function dothis()
{
    $data_insert = array('message' => 'hello');
    $this->db->trans_begin(); //Manually start transaction.
    $this->message_mdl->insert($data_insert);
    $this->db->trans_rollback(); //Rollback
}
```

Make sure that you **don't use** `$this->db->trans_off();` at all.